# IOS 7 apply action on push notification without clicking the message

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

Hi I am developing an app that is considered to track employees with gps and send these information to the server so the manager can easily know their movements

I can do this when the app in a background state
But if the person closed the app can I send a regular push notification that only make my send the current geo location to the server or store to the local DB.

I need a push notification without a message but it apply an action to be done.

Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please see **Edit** section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Receiving push notification isn't guaranteeing that application would be launched. It would be launched only if user taps on push notification. In your case where notification is without message user won't see notification and as result he can't tap on it to launch application.

**--Edit--**
As [@Daij-Djan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420303/daij-djan) noticed there is new feature for receiving silent push notifications that is available from iOS 7. iOS will launch application if such type of notification is received.
For support this feature you need:

1. Include the `UIBackgroundModes` key with the `remote-notification` value in your app’s `Info.plist` file.
2. Implement [application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) method in your app delegate class.

**--Finish Edit--**

Also I could advice to use [startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges) method of CLLocationManager.
By using it iOS automatically will launch application when iPhone location is changed significantly (about 500 meters). So you can send new location every time when this method is called.

Apple docs:

> **If you start this service and your application is subsequently
> terminated, the system automatically relaunches the application into
> the background if a new event arrives.** In such a case, the options
> dictionary passed to the locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method of
> your application delegate contains the key
> UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to indicate that your
> application was launched because of a location event.
>
> **Note:** Apps can
> expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters or more
> from its previous notification. It should not expect notifications
> more frequently than once every five minutes. If the device is able to
> retrieve data from the network, the location manager is much more
> likely to deliver notifications in a timely manner.

Comment: in ios 7 you can use a silent push notification, so this seems invalid given the question speaks about ios7 in the title

Answer (score 2):

You should use the location update mechanism `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` of `CLLocationManager`.

Doing a network call in background can be tricky.

See this link for more info:
http://www.mindsizzlers.com/2011/07/ios-background-location/

Comment: given the question really is about GPS, this seems best

Comment: @Daij-Djan please suggest a good title, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in ios 7 you can use a silent push notification

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: ? how isnt this an answer...